# Processing "success" string returned from servlet via ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, extjs

I have a servlet which accepts my ajax request which passes username and password as params from my LoginView in my ExtJs project .Here is the code for the same :

```
public class UserLoginController  extends MultiActionController {
OrgTreeService orgTreeService;

ModelAndView mv;
public String getLoginStatus(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse)
        throws Exception{
    String str1 = paramHttpServletRequest.getParameter("user");
    String str2 = paramHttpServletRequest.getParameter("password");
    String s="";
      System.out.println("---node"+str1);
      System.out.println("---node"+str2);
      if(str1.equals("admin") && str2.equals("admin")){
          s="success";
      }else{
          s="failure";
      }


      return s;
}
```

and this is how I am making the ajax request from my View:

```
doLoginClicked : function() {
    console.log("button pressed this time");
    var name = this.view.getUsername();
    var pass = this.view.getPassword();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(pass);

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'login/getLoginStatus.action',
        method:'post',
        params: {
            user: name,
            password: pass
            }
    ,
            success: function(response) {


                console.log(response);



                if (response=="success") { 

                  //  login.close(); 


                } else {
                    console.log("inside failure");


                    Ext.Msg.show({
                        title:'Fail!',
                        msg: response, 
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK

                    });
                }
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                console.log("inside failure");

                  Ext.Msg.show({
                        title:'Error!',
                        msg: response,
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    });
                }
        });
    }
```

It does show the username and password in the console from the servlet,But I am not able to accept the "success" response from the servlet and act accordingly.Here is the response that is being shown in the browser console :

```
Object {request: Object, requestId: 1, status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseText: ""…}getAllResponseHeaders: () {arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: response.getAllResponseHeadersconstructor: () {arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: response.getAllResponseHeaders__proto__: Empty() {}<function scope>__proto__: Object__proto__: Empty() {}<function scope>getResponseHeader: (header) {request: Objectasync: truebinary: falseheaders: Objectid: 1options: Object__proto__: ObjectrequestId: 1responseText: ""responseXML: nullstatus: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
```

Is there a way so that I could display the the home page when "Success" is returned from the servlet?

Comment: If you do the request in an http client (postman, curl, whatever), does the server return what you expect ?

Comment: Are you getting the `success` or the `failure` string from the servlet in the `responseText` variable?

Comment: @phtrivier It Does show success message in my IDE console when printed from the servlet and now it shows Internal Server Error 500 after the username and password are processed

Here is the error 
http://gyazo.com/e889e44dbaf6b6d5f8506ceb61784065

Comment: @rawatdeepesh The error in your image seems to be on the *client* side. When receiving a 500, you probably have an Exception on the *server* side (most likely because the request does not have a "user" or "password" parameter, and either str1 or str2 ends up being null.)

Answer (score 0):

`success: function(response)`

the `response` in the above line of code is an object. You will have to go a little deeper into your object, for eg, `response.status == '200'` or `response.responseText == "success"`.

As you have not given the exact response that you are getting, I will not be able to provide the exact code, but this is what the problem look to be.

Comment: Hi Rupesh, It gave same response for correct as well as incorrect username and password .After changing the servlet condition , the IDE console does show if it was a success or not ,but it gives an error while giving the response back , Here is the error:


http://gyazo.com/e889e44dbaf6b6d5f8506ceb61784065